# How can I parse a string that consists of a word followed by numbers into a string followed by an int

Tags: java, string, parsing, int

Let's say the user inputs "hello 0 1" into a string. How can I separate this string into a string that says "hello" followed by two separate ints 0 and 1? I've tried using the substring method with the parameters (0,userInput.nextInt()) and this doesn't work.

Comment: How about splitting it at space and parsing the results?

Comment: Your code does not read an integer from the string.  It reads an integer from the standard input, and uses that as one of the arguments to [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-).  Unfortunately, I don't think you have figured out that computers are actually quite stupid.  They will do exactly what you tell them to do, whether it's what you mean or not.  You can't just throw stuff together any old vague way and expect the compiler to figure out your intent.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that it still reading the numbers as characters, but unfortunately I got stumped for words (working really late at night so I apologize if I gave lousy info on what I'm trying to do), but now I finally figured out what I'm supposed to do!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way:

```
String teststring = "hello 0 1";
String[] splitstr = teststring.split(" ");
String firstString = splitstr[0];
int firstNo = Integer.valueOf(splitstr[1]);
int secondNo = Integer.valueOf(splitstr[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways in which you can extract numbers. Split string or use tokenizer to create token like:

```
String str = "Hello 10 11";
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str);
String token;
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    token = tokenizer.nextToken();
    if (token.matches("\\d+" )) {//if its a number
        System.out.println("Number is " + token);
    }
}
```

You are doing substring by reading a number from system input which you could automate but would be tedious.

Answer (score 0):

If you String contains Spaces , then Splitting it using space as delimeter is an option

```
String []splittedString=inputString.split(" ");//Splitting on basis of space
```

Alternatively you can use ***Regular expression***

```
public static void findWordFollowedByInt()
{
      String inputString="Hello 1 2";
      Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\w+");
      Matcher matcher=p.matcher(hello);
      while(matcher.find())
     {
       System.out.println(matcher.group());
     }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Hello
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Split along the spaces as others have said. Then use something like the Apache commons Lang, which has numberutils that can check if a string is a number. If it is, you can then do something like Double.parseDouble(str).